# Why hash table is sorted?

Tags: java, hashmap

Why hash table(`java.util.HashMap`) is sorted for *long*, *int*, *byte* and *short* ?

See code bellow:

```
public class Main {

    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Map<Long, Long> longMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        final Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        final Map<Byte, Byte> byteMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        final Map<Short, Short> shortMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);

        final Map<Double, Double> doubleMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        final Map<Float, Float> floatMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        final Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> bigDecimalMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        final Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>(INITIAL_CAPACITY);

        final Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){

            int value = random.nextInt(10);
            longMap.put(Long.valueOf(value), Long.valueOf(value));
            integerMap.put(Integer.valueOf(value), Integer.valueOf(value));
            byteMap.put(Byte.valueOf((byte)value), Byte.valueOf((byte)value));
            shortMap.put(Short.valueOf((short)value), Short.valueOf((short)value));

            doubleMap.put(Double.valueOf(value), Double.valueOf(value));
            floatMap.put(Float.valueOf(value), Float.valueOf(value));
            bigDecimalMap.put(BigDecimal.valueOf(value), BigDecimal.valueOf(value));
            stringMap.put(String.valueOf(value), String.valueOf(value));
        }

        System.out.println("\n========== SORTED ==========\n");
        System.out.println("Map<Long, Long>:             " + longMap);
        System.out.println("Map<Integer, Integer>:       " + integerMap);
        System.out.println("Map<Byte, Byte>:             " + byteMap);
        System.out.println("Map<Short, Short>:           " + shortMap);
        System.out.println("\n======== NOT SORTED ========\n");
        System.out.println("Map<Double, Double>:         " + doubleMap);
        System.out.println("Map<Float, Float>:           " + floatMap);
        System.out.println("Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>: " + bigDecimalMap);
        System.out.println("Map<String, String>: " + stringMap);
    }

}
```

Output this program:

```
========== SORTED ==========

Map<Long, Long>             : {0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=7, 8=8, 9=9}
Map<Integer, Integer>       : {0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=7, 8=8, 9=9}
Map<Byte, Byte>             : {0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=7, 8=8, 9=9}
Map<Short, Short>           : {0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=7, 8=8, 9=9}

======== NOT SORTED ========

Map<Double, Double>         : {0.0=0.0, 3.0=3.0, 6.0=6.0, 7.0=7.0, 2.0=2.0, 1.0=1.0, 4.0=4.0, 9.0=9.0, 8.0=8.0, 5.0=5.0}
Map<Float, Float>           : {1.0=1.0, 0.0=0.0, 4.0=4.0, 3.0=3.0, 5.0=5.0, 2.0=2.0, 8.0=8.0, 9.0=9.0, 7.0=7.0, 6.0=6.0}
Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> : {6=6, 0=0, 5=5, 9=9, 7=7, 8=8, 3=3, 4=4, 2=2, 1=1}
Map<String, String>         : {3=3, 2=2, 1=1, 0=0, 7=7, 6=6, 5=5, 4=4, 9=9, 8=8}
```

Comment: There's nothing anywhere that specifies any of them is sorted. Whatever sorting you're seeing is fortuitous and not to be relied on.

Comment: The sorting is based on the fact the implementers have not gone out of there way to complicate the implementation.  There are simple use cases where you get a straight forward outcome.  As you keep adding integer keys you will see the arrangement is pseudo random.  The capacity and load factor play a role and if you make the capacity 1 and the load factor 100, you will see the keys in the reverse order you added them. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/order-of-elements-in-hash-collection.html

Comment: BTW The true capacity of a HashMap is a power of 2 with the default being 16, so when you set the capacity to 10, this is the same as not setting it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for `Long`, `Integer`, `Byte` and `Short` the overridden `int hashCode()` method is trivial and returns the numeric value itself. Since the hashcode is used to index the specific bucket in which the element is placed inside the hashmap, a lower hash results in a lower index. Mind that the preserved order is just apparent: by adding other elements to the hash map it's likely that more element will be placed inside the same bucket so what you see is not guaranteed, it is just a side effect that may arise. **`HashMap` is not a sorted collection and you should not use it as such**. `TreeMap` is the way to go when you need sorted pairs.

For `Double`, `Float`, `BigInteger` and `String` the hash code function is less trivial thus order is not preserved.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is not sorted, your results are simply accidental. Try this

```
    Map<Long, Long> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put(1001L, 1001L);
    m.put(1000L, 1000L);
    m.put(1002L, 1002L);
    System.out.println(m);
```

output

```
{1001=1001, 1000=1000, 1002=1002}
```

-- no sorting